# .NET 6 API - How to Stream File without buffering

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am creating an ASP.NET API that accepts files to be uploaded to a blob storage container.

I am currently using the `IFormFile` which if my understanding is correct loads a file into memory or (depending on the size of the file) disk for buffering.

Is there any way that you can ingest the file through an asp.net API without loading the whole file into memory or disk?

Comment: Use FTP : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-upload-files-with-ftp

Comment: That depends. If you can change the client, streaming the request body is easier than streaming the file from a submitted multipart/form-data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was approaching the problem in the incorrect way. It seems that the best solution was to not send files through the API to blob storage, but to send files directly to blob storage from the client.

Using the blob storage client, files can be uploaded from the client directly. This seems to be the most scalable solution that I have come across so far.

Answer (score 1):

actually if you don't access any property on the `IFormFile`, ASP.NET Core will not totally load that file.

For example. if you do this in controller:

```cs
var _ = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault()?.ContentType;
```

To get that content type, it requires the file to be totally uploaded.

However, if you want to sync that file to another place, you can use `file.CopyToAsync(stream)`.

And the `stream` can be other places like a blob storage container or file on disk.

Example:

```cs
        public async Task Save(IFormFile file)
        {
            using var fileStream = new FileStream("myfile.dat", FileMode.Create);
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This isn't right. You can set a breakpoint on the first line of code in your controller and your breakpoint won't get hit until the file has fully uploaded or the client disconnects mid transfer. Meanwhile, the authentication token could also expire before the upload has finished, as it is also not validated until the upload is completed. If what you say is true, then in that scenario the breakpoint should be hit immediately as soon as the request comes in and the file starts transferring.